# Visual Studio 2013 randomly changes the theme on its own

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I seem to be having a terribly annoying issue with Visual Studio 2013.
I am using the "default" Dark theme on my environment, but every few minutes or so it changes its theme to another, which is not even a theme I have on my machine.

Has anyone else experienced this? How does one solve it?

PS.: Logged in on a shared, corporate account

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the fact that Synchronized Settings were enabled, therefore it was trying to sync theme and other settings across different machines.

Solution:
In VS13, go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Synchronized Settings and then uncheck the "Enabled synchronization" box.

Comment: I would suggest an update : in VS 2017, the box is in "Tools -> Options -> Environment -> **Accounts**"

Comment: "Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Accounts" also for 2019

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio will change its theme to default if your computer is struggling to keep up with the graphical requirements.

You can change this by unchecking `Options > Environment > General > "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance"`.

Comment: The theme that's being assigned is by no means default, though. Also, it changes to a different theme repeatedly, not just once.

Comment: Well the theme will carry on changing if Visual Studio deems the computer can't keep up :) 

Has the default theme been edited in some way? Perhaps someone has changed it through share?

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this happen. The only thing I can think is that another user is also using the same account, but with a different theme, causing your shared settings to be updated, and causing your theme to change.

And probably if you keep changing the theme back, I bet your colleague will be having the same problem as you :)